# delete sobre mas de un elemento

Tags: mysql

quisiera eliminar mas de un dato de db , estoy tratando de usar esta consulta

```
 delete usuario,categoria from usuario
        INNER JOIN
    categoria ON usuario.usuario_idCategoria = categoria.idCategoria
WHERE categoria.idCategoria = 10;
```

mis tablas son

| Usuario | Categoria |
| --- | --- |
| idusuario | idCategoria |
| User | categoria |
| usuario_idCategoria |  |

usuario_idCategoria es la fk de Categoria y tengo los siguientes datos :

Tabla Usuario

| idusuario | user | usuario_idCategoria |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | pedro | 10 |
| 2 | juan | 10 |
| 3 | miguel | 11 |

Tabla Categoria

| idCategoria | categoria |
| --- | --- |
| 10 | usuario |
| 11 | admin |
| 12 | moderador |

entonces estoy tratando de eliminar dos usuarios de la categoria usuario pero al parecer no me deja mysql y me tira el siguiente error
**#1451 - Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails**

Comment: Comienza por quitar `categoria` del `DELETE`, por que ya la incluyes en el JOIN. Aunque ¿para qué haces el JOIN si `idCategoria` es parámetro?

Comment: es que en realidad estoy tratando de eliminar la categoria , pero no puedo eliminarla ya que los usuarios estan relacionados a esta

Answer (score 1):

Como tu tabla Categoría tiene relación con Usuarios, y lo que quieres es borrar una categoría en concreto, entonces lo que tienes que hacer es primer borrar los usuarios en con la categoría que quieres borrar en concreto, es decir:

```
--Se borran los usuarios con categoria 10 (no es necesario hacer un INNER JOIN)
DELETE FROM usuario u WHERE u.usuario_idCategoria = 10
```

Una vez borrado los usuarios entonces, podemos borrar la categoría:

```
DELETE FROM categoria c WHERE c.idCategoria = 10
```

OJO, esto es un borrado físico, si lo que quieres es un borrado lógico para no perder los datos definitivamente te recomiendo poner un campo más en cada tabla que controle si está borrado o no

Comment: hola gracias pero no puedo juntar esas dos consultas en una sola ?

Answer (score 0):

Para unir esas dos en uno, puedes hacer lo siguiente :

```
DELETE FROM usuario, categoria WHERE categoria.idCategoria=usuario.idCategoria 
AND usuario.usuario_idCategoria=10;
```